# How to prevent ajax call from firing twice

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an `ajax` call which is fired when a `click` event occurs on `document`. The ajax call seems to be executing `twice` and I am not sure why this happens.

This is running on `MySQL 5`, `PHP 5` and `Apache 2`

**My question is :** How can I prevent ajax call from firing `twice`?

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_quyet_dinh', function(){  
    var ma_quyet_dinh = $(this).attr("id");
    var ma_cong_trinh = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({  
        url:"fetch_quyet_dinh.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{ma_quyet_dinh:ma_quyet_dinh,ma_cong_trinh:ma_cong_trinh},  
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){  
            $('#ten_quyet_dinh').val(data.ten_cong_trinh);  
            $('#shct_qd').val(data.so_hieu);  
            $('#so_quyet_dinh').val(data.so_quyet_dinh);  
            $('#ngay_duyet').val(data.ngay_duyet);  
            $('#ma_quyet_dinh').val(data.ma_quyet_dinh);  
            $('#insert_qd').val("Update");  
            $('#add_quyet_dinh').modal('show');  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Comment: Could you put `console.log("X");` before ajax call and `console.log("Y")` inside ajax call? then let us know what you get.

Comment: @Feelsbadman: I put console.log("X") before ajax call. Console tab wrote: [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Comment: Do you have dynamic content or html? I was have same problem that because it. My solution was change `$(document)` to `$("#div")` ,I think you should put the full code in js fiddle or something like that

Comment: @Muhammad Dyas: I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_quyet_dinh', function(event){  
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();

   // other codes
});
```

this method stopped twice call jquery event function.

> **stopPropagation** stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.
>
> **preventDefault** prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

Comment: Abbas: I use your code, but sometimes it executes fetch_quyet_dinh.php file twice.